# PHP need advice better method CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

I'm building a web apps using CI framework with 2 controllers 'dashboard' and 'projects', in dashboard controller I have scripts for getting list of projects:

(dashboard controller)

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

    function __contruct()
    {
        parent::__contruct()
        $project_id = array('projectid' = '');

        // remove project id session userdata
        $this->session->unset_userdata($project_id);
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("content_model");

        // getting project list
        $this->data['projects'] = $this->content_model->get_content();

        // rendering view
        $this->_render_page('dashboard/index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

(dashboard index view)

```
<html>
<?php foreach ($projects as $project):?>
    <?php echo anchor("projects/index/".$project->id, 'Project', 'title="List Project"');?>
<?php endforeach;?>
</html>
```

above scripts will generate a links to my project controller as shown below:

```
<a href="http://me.com/projects/index/1" title="List Project">Project</a>
<a href="http://me.com/projects/index/2" title="List Project">Project</a>
<a href="http://me.com/projects/index/3" title="List Project">Project</a>
```

A number 1, 2, 3 ..etc in above links is ids of projects, so in second controller (I call it project controller) I will set this ids to session userdata:

(projects controller)

```
class Projects extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("project_model");
    }

    function index($projectid = NULL)
    {
        // checking for id
        if ($projectid !== null && !is_numeric($projectid))
        {
            header("refresh:4;url=".base_url('dashboard'));
            return show_404();
        }

        // set project ids to session userdata
        $ses = array('projectid' => $projectid);
        $this->session->set_userdata($ses);

        // querying get data of project
        $this->project_model->data_project($projectid);
    }

    // add goods to project
    function add_goods()
    {
        // get project id from session
        $projectid = $this->session->userdata('projectid');

        // get input form value
        $form_data = array(
            'name'   => $this->input->post('name'),
            'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
            'note'  => $this->input->post('note'),
        );

        // querying save goods to related project
        $this->project_model->add_goods_project($projectid, $form_data);

        // redirect
        redirect('projects/goods', 'refresh');
    }

    // remove goods from project
    function remove_goods($goodid=false)
    {
        // get project id from session
        $projectid  = $this->session->userdata('projectid');

        // querying remove goods from related project
        $this->project_model->remove_goods_project($projectid, $goodid);

        // redirect
        redirect('projects/goods', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

After set projects ids to session userdata, it will easy to me querying data related projects from database.

```
// get project id from session
$projectid = $this->session->userdata('projectid');

// querying save goods to related project
$this->project_model->add_goods_project($projectid, $form_data);

// querying remove goods from related project
$this->project_model->remove_goods_project($projectid, $goodid);
```

But after all I think this method will not effective if user open multiple projects link in diffrent tabs, it will mess up all querying database. Since session data only have 1 ids of project.

I need someone suggest me (advise) a better method so user can enjoy open multiple projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With cookie-based session management, a browser can only support one session at a time. This works for the vast majority of web sites. To support multiple sessions in one browser, you'd need to use URL-based session management which is tricky and error-prone.

You just need to configure it properly:

- no underscore in the cookie name
- cookie hostname and path must be correct
- hostname needs to be valid (needs one, in some case two dots in the name, so localhost is invalid!)
- make sure the time on the server is correct ( ntp )
- when using timeouts, cater for users in different timezones
- when using timeouts, cater for users with an incorrectly set PC clock
- when using ajax, avoid a sess_update() call for ajax requests ( search the forum for a solution )

When using a client-side solution that can't sent cookies (p.e. swf's), have it send the session_id as a post variable. Then extend the session library, so that it checks for this variable via $this->input->post() when the cookie can not be found, and use that to load the session instead.

Hope this idea Helps :-)